# TTL expired sstables not getting dropped on Cassandra Nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am inserting data in below table with TTL of 2 days. SSTABLES with timestamp older than 2 days should have been dropped but that is not happening. There are no deletes and no updates. Window size is 1 hour and gc_grace_seconds is 7200. read_repair has been set to 0.0

```
CREATE TABLE events."290" (
    key text PRIMARY KEY,
    raw_log text
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 'compaction_window_size': '1', 'compaction_window_unit': 'HOURS', 'max_threshold': '64', 'min_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 7200
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = 'NONE';
```

On restarting cassandra the expired sstables got removed as expected.

Should I be setting unchecked_tombstone_compaction = true? 
Ideally I would like the sstables to be dropped completely rather than go through multiple compactions to get removed.

Earlier I was using DateTieredCompaction and cassandra 2.2. Everything was working fine. Upgraded to cassandra 3.0.13 and observed above behaviour. Changed compaction from DTCS to TWCS and still the same behaviour.

If on restarting the expired sstables were not getting removed, I would have considered case of overlapping sstables https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13418

Comment: I was having the same issue in cassandra 3.8, and needs to update `unchecked_tombstone_compaction` to true along with `gc_grace_period`. Then after upgrade to 3.11.1 recently, everything seems to be working fine for us.

Comment: @Apolozeus . Were you setting gc_grace_seconds to 0 or some low value?

Comment: I used low value only

Comment: by coincidence I watched this last night [Tombstone Compactions in Cassandra](https://youtu.be/pher-9jqqC4) and I think it answers a lot of your questions. Also this talk [How Cassandra Deletes Data](https://youtu.be/lReTEcnzl7Y) was very interesting. Tombstones last a lot longer than gc_grace_seconds.

Comment: @LHWizard thanks for the video, it's worth watching for better understanding on cassandra